# How to remove your name from the menu bar after 10.7.5 update?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

After the 10.7.5 update to Lion, I'm getting my name to appear in the menu bar. I don't particularly like it there. Any way to remove it?

[image: image showing issue]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Users & Groups

At the bottom of the user list click the 'Login Options' item and then make sure 'Show fast user switching menu as ...' is unchecked.

That'll get rid of fast user switching from the menu bar for you.

[image]

Comment: Ha! a skitch gunfight

Comment: Ahhh. Login Options -- how intuitive!

Gave you the checkmark because you you were ~1 minute faster at the gun. :)

Comment: WAT - I won that race by more than a minute ;-) But seriously - pick the answer you __like best__ and not just the one that was first. (you can see the times change and refresh and for some of the time mine is two minutes older and others it's only one minute older).

Answer (score 4):

Have you changed it under Users & Groups preference pane after the update?

[image: Users & Groups]

Once you select Login Options in the lower left, choose icon or short name or deselect this item entirely to remove the user from the menu bar.

Comment: Pew. Pew. Git yer Skitch guns out!